# Tracking Development and Deployment of work items from Board view

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Repository source - GitHub

We recently migrated to GitHub as source of repository and Pipelines are still in Azure DevOps, I am trying to get the work items linked to build pipelines but found out that this option is not available for external repositories and only works with Azure Repos.

Now I am aware that we can link commits and PRs to Development section in work item, but is there any way we can track deployments too with current setup?

Tried - linking commits to development section by AB#itemnumber, works fine, but can't find anything to view deployments in work item view

Expecting - to track development and deployment in work item view with GitHub as source repository.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04VCk.png)

Comment: If you are using the  Classic release pipeline, you can refer my answer to make it work. If you are using the yaml pipeline, it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Deployment control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-link?view=azure-devops#deployment-control)'s note

> The Deployment control requires configuration of a Classic release pipeline. It doesn't support linking to release stages defined for a YAML pipeline with stages.

I have tested the Classic release pipeline with GitHub as source repository, and I found it works.

My Steps:

1. Create a build pipeline (yaml pipeline or classic build pipeline) and commits to development section by [using AB# to link from GitHub to Azure Boards work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/link-to-from-github?view=azure-devops#use-ab-to-link-from-github-to-azure-boards-work-items). The build pipeline should publish a build artifact.
2. Create a Classic release pipeline and add the build artifact in the release pipeline. Enable the Continuous deployment trigger in the Artifacts section.
   [image]
3. Enable the report deployment status to Boards in the options.
   [image]
4. Commit with AB#ID to trigger the build pipeline. After the classic release pipeline is triggered by the build artifact and finishes, the deployment information will show up in deployment session of the work item.

[image]